# kafka to sparkstreaming to HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, apache-kafka

I am using creatDirectStream in order to integrate SparkStreaming and Kafka. Here is the code that I used:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf, Seconds(10))
    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "sandbox:6667")
    val topics = Set("topic1")

    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

Now I want to store messages into HDFS. Is it right to do this?

```
messages.saveAsTextFiles("/tmp/spark/messages")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`saveAsTextFiles("/tmp/spark/messages")` - This will persist your data in local file system and in case the provided folder structure ("/tmp/spark/messages") is part of your local HDFS then it will also show in HDFS directory because `saveAsTextFiles` leverages the same MapeReduce API's to write the output.

The above will work in scenarios where Spark Executors and HDFS are on same physical machines but in case your HDFS directory or URL is different and not on the same machines, where executors are running, then this will not work.

In case you need to ensure that your data is persisted in HDFS, then as a good practice you should  always provide the complete HDFS URL. something like this - `saveAsTextFiles("http://<HOST-NAME>:9000/tmp/spark/messages")`

or you can also leverage either of the following methods: -

1. `DStream.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFiles(<HDFS URL with Location>)`
2. `DStream.saveAsHadoopFiles(<HDFS URL with Location>)`

Comment: I don't know if this is true in all cases, I'm using the normal path and it goes to hdfs by default

Comment: That's not true either, it will create the folders of they aren't there, or you can save to root of you want

Comment: @SebastianPiu - I never said that it will not create folders. You may need to read my answer again. There is a difference when you provide the complete HDFS URL against just the folder path. Again it is a good practice to always supply the complete URL+path

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying then, I'm doing just that and is NOT saving in the localsystem and it goes straight to HDFS, is that what you mean?

Comment: In your case the executors are running on the same machine where you have HDFS and you have dedicated whole disk to be part of HDFS,  so it works. Now think of scenario where your executor are running on a different machine and HDFS is on different node or you have defined specific folders of the disk to be part of HDFS which does not necessarily starts from root of your system. In these cases you need to specify the complete HDFS URL and that's the reason it is always advised to specify complete HDFS URL.

Comment: that makes sense, but is not what your answer implies in the first couple of lines - which is the point I was trying to make

Comment: The messages in the above example is "DirectStream" which contain Kafka messages. My question is, is it a right way to store the Kafka message into HDFS, using messages.saveAs...("PATH")?

Comment: I do not see any issue in that but depending upon the message size/ rate you may need to think of using another variation of `saveAsTextFile(...)` which accepts `CompressionCodec` as a second argument or may be use   `saveAsObjectFiles` for storing as Hadoop Sequence Files but that will solely depend upon your use case.

Comment: Spark Streaming messages are [key , value] by default. When I am using DStream.saveAsTextFiles is going to create file with a null key and a value. How can I say just right the value ?